# How can I speed my Entity Framework code?

Tags: sql, performance, entity-framework

My SQL and Entity Framework knowledge is a somewhat limited. In one Entity Framework (4) application, I notice it takes forever (about 2 minutes) to complete one of my method calls. The first queries do not take much time, but when I loop through the Entity Framework objects returned by the queries, even though I am only reading (not modifying) the data I supposedly got, it takes forever to complete the nested loops, even though there are only dozens of entries in each list and a few levels of looping.

I expect the example below could be re-written with a fancier query that could probably include all of the filtering I am doing in my loops with some SQL words I don't really know how to use, so if someone could show me what the equivalent SQL expression would be, that would be extremely educational to me and probably solve my current performance problem.

Moreover, since other parts of this and other applications I develop often want to do more complex computations on SQL data, I would also like to know a good way to retrieve data from Entity Framework to local memory objects that do not have huge delays in reading them. In my LINQ-to-SQL project there was a similar performance problem, and I solved it by refactoring the whole application to load all SQL data into parallel objects in RAM, which I had to write myself, and I wonder if there isn't a better way to either tell Entity Framework to not keep doing whatever high-latency communication it is doing, or to load into local RAM objects.

In the example below, the code gets a list of food menu items for a member (i.e. a person) on a certain date via a SQL query, and then I use other queries and loops to filter out the menu items on two criteria: 1) If the member has a rating of zero for any group id which the recipe is a member of (a many-to-many relationship) and 2) If the member has a rating of zero for the recipe itself.

Example:

```
List<PFW_Member_MenuItem> MemberMenuForCookDate =
            (from item in _myPfwEntities.PFW_Member_MenuItem
             where item.MemberID == forMemberId
             where item.CookDate == onCookDate
             select item).ToList();

        // Now filter out recipes in recipe groups rated zero by the member:
        List<PFW_Member_Rating_RecipeGroup> ExcludedGroups =
            (from grpRating in _myPfwEntities.PFW_Member_Rating_RecipeGroup
             where grpRating.MemberID == forMemberId
             where grpRating.Rating == 0
             select grpRating).ToList();
        foreach (PFW_Member_Rating_RecipeGroup grpToExclude in ExcludedGroups)
        {
            List<PFW_Member_MenuItem> rcpsToRemove = new List<PFW_Member_MenuItem>();
            foreach (PFW_Member_MenuItem rcpOnMenu in MemberMenuForCookDate)
            {
                PFW_Recipe rcp = GetRecipeById(rcpOnMenu.RecipeID);
                foreach (PFW_RecipeGroup group in rcp.PFW_RecipeGroup)
                {
                    if (group.RecipeGroupID == grpToExclude.RecipeGroupID)
                    {
                        rcpsToRemove.Add(rcpOnMenu);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (PFW_Member_MenuItem rcpToRemove in rcpsToRemove)
                MemberMenuForCookDate.Remove(rcpToRemove);
        }
        // Now filter out recipes rated zero by the member:
        List<PFW_Member_Rating_Recipe> ExcludedRecipes =
            (from rcpRating in _myPfwEntities.PFW_Member_Rating_Recipe
             where rcpRating.MemberID == forMemberId
             where rcpRating.Rating == 0
             select rcpRating).ToList();
        foreach (PFW_Member_Rating_Recipe rcpToExclude in ExcludedRecipes)
        {
            List<PFW_Member_MenuItem> rcpsToRemove = new List<PFW_Member_MenuItem>();
            foreach (PFW_Member_MenuItem rcpOnMenu in MemberMenuForCookDate)
            {
                if (rcpOnMenu.RecipeID == rcpToExclude.RecipeID)
                    rcpsToRemove.Add(rcpOnMenu);
            }
            foreach (PFW_Member_MenuItem rcpToRemove in rcpsToRemove)
                MemberMenuForCookDate.Remove(rcpToRemove);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure about this because to be honest I've not used entity framework much (or at all really) but seeing as you are using linq queries, I'd imagine that the `ToList()` calls are probably executing immediately (instead of being deferred) and you are bringing back way too much data.

Comment: It's a different application that uses LINQ, but I don't know what you mean, and it may be the same in Entity Framework. The ToList calls end up creating lists that are only 1-3 dozen entries long, and don't take much time to execute. The 2 minutes are being spent in the loops below the ToList calls, as I can see from debugging (it goes immediately to the top of the loops), and it didn't take long before I put in the loops.

Comment: 1. get list of recipeid from ExcludedRecipes  2. get list of recipeid from ExcludedGroups. 3. merge two list together, 4. search PFW_Member_MenuItem which does not contain the recipeids.  5. User Linqpad to get the query and run in sql server to get exection plan. add index if needed

Comment: First of: profile to see where the slowdown occurs. (Also consider splitting up your code into helper functions so the profile will give you more readable results.) My hunch however is that you're lazily-initialising the relationship collections you're iterating over in the nested loops, so the problem is that you keep having to make roundtrips to the database. Try using `.Include()` to make sure you fetch your whole object graph in one go. (After verifying that the time is spent somewhere inside Entity Framework when calling code that doesn't use it directly.)

Comment: @millimoose Sounds likely - I'm looking up now what you mean by .Include().

Comment: @millimoose No joy trying to guess what to tell it to .Include(). Every string I pass in gives me an exception about "A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'PfwModel.PFW_Member_MenuItem' does not declare a navigation property with the name ___"

Comment: @Dronz If you used `DbContext` instead of `ObjectContext`, you could use the version of `Include` that takes an Expression instead of a string. Otherwise, no idea, `ObjectContext`-based EF is mostly a mystery to me, it's possible the relationships have a different name in the model than they do in code.

Comment: If I have my queries only fetch columns rather than objects, will it give me nice fast RAM objects that have nothing to do with the database, that I can loop through quickly? I have the feeling that might work...

Answer (score 2):

You can use EFProf http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf to track see exactly what EF is sending to SQL.  It can also show you how many queries you are sending and how many unique queries.  It also provides you some analysis of each query (e.g. is it unbound etc).  Entity Framework with its navigation properties, it is quite easy to not realize you are making a db request.  When you are in a loop, and have a navigation property, you get in to the N + 1 problem.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I will look into EFProf.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Keyword Virtual on your List parts of your model if you are using code first to enable proxying, that way you will not have to get all the data back at once, only as you need it.

Also consider NoTracking for read only data

```
context.bigTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

Comment: Thanks Nikos. I just found that suggestion elsewhere and have been trying it out. I am down to about 45 seconds though I think that's because it is a looping problem and my data is smaller today. The syntax I needed was a bit more elaborate because I needed to make a separate query object so as not to set the merge option for the entire app.